# Why target function is minimized at (0,0) if I can get to a negative number?

Tags: linear-programming

I just started learning LP and I saw this Q in my textbook:

```
min  : "-x -y"
S.T. : x + 2y <= 3, 2x +y <= 3, x >=0, y >= 0
```

It is easy to see that the polygon created from these constrains can't have a negative coordinate. In my textbook it says the answer is (0,0) since *`-0 -0 = 0`* and this is the minimum value of the target function (i.e. *`"f(x,y) = -x -y"`*).

My question is why is that the minimum? If I choose any other values (S.T. the constrains) I can get, for example, (1,1) which will result in *`-1 -1 = -2 < 0`* !!

Another thing that I don't understand - would there be a difference if my function was different? If the min is (0,0) - wouldn't it be the case for any other *`f(x,y) = a*x + b*y`* for any other *`a,b`*?

Comment: Ask for a refund.

Comment: What do you mean? Is the book wrong?

Comment: Yes, Or may be you read it wrong. (could it be min x+y = max -x-y?)

Comment: No. it is as I said :( (could be that a fix was released afterwards)